# IE9 vuejs app receiving 415 from django rest framework server

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, internet-explorer-9

I've been stuck with this issue, seems like the reason receiving 415 is because IE9 does not send any `CONTENT_TYPE` header. But is there any workaround for this one? Everything works perfectly on other browser except for IE9

Comment: What are you using to send the request to the api? Axios? jQuery? Raw XHR?

Comment: hi phillip, we are using axios

Comment: Have you confirmed (through a network trace) that IE9 is not sending the header?  Are you setting the content-type in your code?  Including the code you're having an issue with would help a lot.

Comment: yeah I alreaedy included that but it's no use